# Is the T-spot blood test sensitive enough to determine difference between exposure to the tuberculosis and tuberculosis vaccination?

Tags: blood-tests, tuberculosis

I wonder whether the T-spot blood test is sensitive enough to determine difference between exposure to the tuberculosis and tuberculosis vaccination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The T-spot blood test for tuberculosis is an interferon-gamma release assay (IGRA or  IFN-γ assay). There are two of these tests (Quantiferon and T-spot) with small differences, but [the basic mechanism](http://www.cdc.gov/tb/publications/factsheets/testing/igra.htm) is the same and they are treated the same for the CDC, [which writes](http://www.cdc.gov/tb/topic/testing/):

> IGRAs, unlike the TB skin tests, are not affected by prior BCG vaccination and are not expected to give a false-positive result in people who have received BCG

BCG is the [tuberculosis vaccine](http://www.vaccines.gov/diseases/tb/).

While I couldn't find references to primary literature on that CDC site, what I found myself supports this

The paper [Discrepancy Between the Tuberculin Skin Test and the Whole-Blood Interferon γ Assay for the Diagnosis of Latent Tuberculosis Infection in an Intermediate Tuberculosis-Burden Country](http://jama.jamanetwork.com/mobile/article.aspx?articleid=201039) concludes

> the IFN-γ assay based on the ESAT-6 and CFP-10 M tuberculosis–specific antigens is a useful method for detecting latent TB infections and might help to eliminate the limitations of the TST [tuberculin skin test] in BCG-vaccinated populations in intermediate TB-burden countries.

[Tuberculosis contact investigation with a new, specific blood test in a low-incidence population containing a high proportion of BCG-vaccinated persons](http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1465-9921-7-77.pdf) reaches the same conclusion and recommends the test for vaccinated people. That study used the Quantiferon test, but the two tests [have roughly the same sensitivity](http://journal.publications.chestnet.org/mobile/article.aspx?articleid=1089749).